# Validating multiple columns - one date, one yes/no

Tags: list, date-time, validation

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make sure that if "yes" in the yes/no option is chosen, that a date must be entered in the "when" column and vice versa.

In summary, did you buy a car? if so When?

I have this^ formula as =IF(Purchased=TRUE,IF([Purchased Date]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)

My main question is **how do I also make sure that if a person enters a "purchase date" that they also checked "Yes" in the "Purchased" column.**

I have been playing with making it a nested If formula as well as making it all an "And" formula, neither of which seem to work. Please advise.

Comment: Just typing of the top of my head so it might not work... ``=OR( NOT([Purchased]) , [Purchased Date] )``  since Date field are also treated as T/F values

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. :(